# React-Native - Babel-Node - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, react-native

In my packages.json, I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node ./server/server.js --presets es2016,stage-2"
  },
```

the server.js has: `import path from 'path';`

at the top.

Running `npm start`, I get the error:

```
/Users/*********/nomad/server/server.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import path from 'path';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at loader (/Users/**********/nomad/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:146:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/**********/nomad/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:156:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at /Users/**********/nomad/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:151:24
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/*********/nomad/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:152:7)
```